# How to Add a Multiline Textbox in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

i need a textbox which can have multiple lines and scrolbar should appear automatically.

The textbox should not be editable.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Memo page (Information before installation)?

That is exactly what you need and intended for large amount of information to be shown.

Please be more specific - what are you trying to achieve?